# TypeScript Type Inference - Generic Object Of Functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

I was trying to implement a generic function that accepts an interface of functions and data, and passes the results from one another.

Inference is broken, any help will be appreciated.

[Link to a CodeSandbox of the Code That Does Not Compile](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-lalande-jk7gx?fontsize=14)

```
function InitViewModel<S, C, M>(params: {
  state: S;
  computed: (s: S) => C;
  methods: (s: S, c: C) => M;
}) {
  const state = params.state;
  const computed = params.computed(state);
  const methods = params.methods(state, computed);
  return {
    state,
    computed,
    methods
  };
}

export const VM = InitViewModel({
  state: { message: "This Will Be Infered As expected" },
  computed: (state /* infered */) => ({
    computedMessage: state.message + " But This Will Not"
  }),
  methods: (state /* infered */, computed /*  inferred wrong */) => {
    return {
      logName: () => console.log(state.message),
      logComputedName: () => console.log(computed.computedMessage) // Does not compile
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: `computed.computedMessage` does not exist because `computed` is a function. Returned value have `computedMessage` so `computed(someStatus).computedMessage` should have more sense. But I didn't understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: @DanieleAlessandra, It is already called the way you've described, I've modified the code to make it more clear.

Comment: @Daniel I have been banging my head for the past 45 mins, don't think there is a way to do this without splitting this in multiple parameters, I just can't get the compiler to do contextual typing for the parameters and get the return type `C` inferred correctly. Might be a limitation in the way these two features work. Maybe someone else has some idea..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir. Thanks for the 45 mins, followed you in Twitter :-) I know about the splitted parameter solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is not possible in the current Typescript version.

I've been experimenting with your code and it seems [Type Inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) work with some internal priority, which dictates that type **should be inferred from parameter when possible, over inference from return value**.

If you'll remove the `methods` parameter from your code, you'll see `computed` return value - `C`, will be inferred correctly as:

```
{ computedMessage: string }
```

When `methods` included,`C` is inferred as `unknown`, since it is exist as a parameter in `methods`, so typescript will prefer to try to get the correct type based on `methods` behavior rather then `computed`.

Comment: Hi @yuval.bl can you give a link to refer to which line of code in [Typescript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript) the priority "should be inferred from parameter when possible, over inference from return value"